# what is scheduler latency?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, scheduler, multitasking

This seems to be a basic question, but i couldn't find answer anywhere in googling it.

As Far As I Understand, scheduler latency is the time incurred in making the task runnable again. I mean, if there are 100 processes namely 1, 2, e.t.c, then they are executed let's say in order starting from 1. So the latency is the time that the process 1 is executed again. which means that the latency is the waiting time of the process as well as the waiting time of it when it is in runqueue ready to execute.

Or

i misunderstood whole point and sheduler latency is just nothing but the context switching time between the processes?

Comment: I always understood latency as the time it takes for a job to complete + the amount of time that job has been waiting.

Comment: @Chris: I always understood latency as the time it takes for a job to begin.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How very bizarre..

Comment: @Chris: While the system is working on a job, it is not latent. When it has work to do but has not started doing it yet, then it is latent.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz which means that my understanding is right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scheduling latency is the time that the system is inproductive because of scheduling tasks. It is system latency incurred because it has to spend time scheduling.

Specifically it consists of 2 elements:

- The delay between a task waking up and actually running (the 'context switching time')
- Time spent making scheduler decisions (the actual job of the scheduler, which consumes resources that cannot be used by real tasks anymore)

Comment: ok, so which means that i misunderstood the whole part?

but how does the context switching latency increase or depends on the number of processes? it walks through a list of runnable processes and decides which is to be run based on priorities. But will this can take up context switching time so long?

Comment: The point of [preemptive multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Preemptive_multitasking) is that its based on fairness - all running threads and processes get their fair bit of time allocated. Scheduling that takes time, and the algorithm obviously gets more costly with added complexity - balancing 1000 processes and their priorities means more pain on the scheduling end than 10, and every time slice lost at that level is felt everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I have found that the waiting time of processes in runqueue as well as the flushing of TLB entries when ever context switching occur, will also increase the latency.