# Difference between scheduling latency and wakeup latency

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time

What is the difference between scheduling latency and wakeup latency

a) to pick a process to run is a scheduler logic and how is this latency important

b) When a process is picked up for running but its not still run, is the wakeup latency IMHO

Can someone help understanding the difference?

Comment: What is the source of these questions?  Is it from a textbook, an implementation of a kernel, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between scheduling latency and wakeup latency?

This is probably understood with answers to your other questions.

> a) to pick a process to run is a scheduler logic and how is this latency important

Imagine you have two tasks and they are both wanting to run.  One will take 5 minutes and the other 4 minutes of real run time to complete.  If you run ping-pong between them for approximately eight minutes the contention should revolve. Each switch may take 100s of microseconds.  If the switch frequency is high, then the overhead might be a significant percentage.  If the 'ticks' is 1mS, then the switch overhead is 10% (with 100uS switch time) and it will take more like 9 minutes to complete the work for the four minute task with a minute still left for the 2nd task.

There are different types of scheduling latency.  One is the time to context switch.  This can involve saving and restoring CPU, floating point and other registers, updating the MMU (memory seen my user space) and deciding what task to switch to.   Caches may also need to be flushed depending on circumstances and possibly migrating the state to a different CPU.  This is the 100uS figure or switch time I used as an example above.

Another issue is the reschedule frequency.  This is how long another process may pre-empt someone of near equal priority.  The two numbers will compete with each other.  Ie, 100uS may be for a very slow CPU, so setting 'ticks' to 10mS will reduce the overhead to only 1% in the example above.  However, the rescheduling responsiveness will decrease when reschedule frequency decreases.

Some people include interrupt latency in **scheduler latency**.  You may need a task to be rescheduled in the event of some important hardware event.  Also there are many different algorithms for 'picking who runs'.  There is probably no right answer for 'who runs' in **all** cases, so there are many different versions.  Linux generally uses the ['completely fair scheduler'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) or CFS.

See: [What is scheduler latency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893797/what-is-scheduler-latency) 
        [EETime article](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1200916) 
        [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/404993/)

> b) When a process is picked up for running but its not still run, is
>   the wakeup latency.

I think that is the 'scheduling latency' as I explained above (but some people may include more items).

Again, the term **wakeup** may be a little ambiguous.  There are different kinds of 'wakeups'.  On modern battery powered systems, the CPU is usually put into low power states when there is no work to be done.  In these cases, the **wakeup** time may add to the scheduling latency.  This is the extra time to get the CPU (and memory, etc) out of a low power state to full speed operation.

---

These terms have no definite definition that I know of and you need to look at the context an author might use them in.  The ideas are similar in each case but the specific details may differ.  Often it depends on the goals or use case.  A person only working on scheduler code will probably include context time and the scheduling algorithm overhead.  Interrupt latency is a separate issue to them.  However, for a fixed embedded system with more real time responsiveness, the interrupt latency matter for the whole system and people may lump them together.

Also, many people (think they) want hard real time.  This is where some task is paramount.  However, often a lower priority task may be about to wait for I/O.  In these cases giving a lower priority task may increase *through-put* or minimize the time to complete a work case.  Often the case for desktop or server examples.   In the through-put optimum, it is best to have tasks waiting for 'I/O' as this parallels the hardware access times.

Comment: In RT testing there is something called wakeup latency. I am getting confused if it includes scheduler latency

Comment: You mean [rt-latency-howto](http://people.redhat.com/williams/latency-howto/rt-latency-howto.txt)?  In this case, they are refering to a task 'wakeup' due to a timer being set.  This is just interrupt+scheduler latency.  The term 'wakeup' is what ever RT-Linux test tool *cyclictest* is using.  There are additional latencies due to cpufreq and other things like *wakelocks* or whatever there Android incarnation is.  Someone might call these 'wake latency' as well.  It would help your question if you reference some material as per **wallyk**.

Comment: For this benchmark, it just matters what relative changes to Linux code does to the benchmark.  It is probably not useful for comparing other OS's.  This is exactly what a Linux RT developer wants.